# Changing time mode in a Digital Clock from 12HR to 24HR in VHDL

Tags: types, concatenation, vhdl

Greetings everyone.

I am designing a digital clock in VHDL which I am supposed to synthesize on a FPGA . I am cascading S1,S2,M1,M2,H1 and H2 where (S1 = second 1, M1 = Minute 1, H1 = hour 1 etc.). 
One of the requirements is for the clock to switch between 24HR display to a 12HR display format. How do I do it given that H1 and H2 are represented by 4 bits each i.e. 8 bits 
in total to display the current hour. Will I need to concatenate HR1 and HR2 and then subtract 12 and then de-concatenate it  again? keep in mind that X mod 12 is not a synthesizable operation for implementation in FPGA.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `mod 12` may not be a synthesisable operation, but it's easy to build mod12 counters...

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are doing all your arithmetic in binary coded decimal (BCD).  So just build yourself a BCD comparator/subtractor:

```
if h1 = 1 and h2 > 2
  subtract 1 off h1
  subtract 2 off h2
  if h2 wrapped
     subtract 1 off h1
```

No mod required!

Answer (score 0):

If you have spare resources, you can double the H registers. Let make H24-1 and H24-2 (as you already have) and H12-1 and H12-2 "mod12" registers beside. Both pairs will be clocked all the times, so you will have both format ready every clock cycle. Than just use some MUX to switch which of them are displayed.